# Access PDF Without making it Public

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have made a file uploader to upload DOC/PDF Files, When the user uploads the file files the default permission is 644, With that when the user who uploaded the files gets Permission denied error when he access the file.

I make it accessible by setting the permission to 777. but that is not secure.

Is there any other way to access PDF without 777 permission?